Relays keep killing my timer IC, how do i protect it?

I recently made this simple circuit to power a small DC motor as part of a power feed mechanism on a milling machine. It uses 2 DPDT relays to decide the polarity of the motor and I have that running through a single mosfet driven by a 7555 timer to give me speed control over the motor with a PWM signal. The polarity is selected with a toggle switch that has 2 on positions and an off position in the middle similar to a rocker switch.
My problem is even though I have diodes across all coils and switch contacts, after only a few direction changes my timer dies so I lose speed control. Before I added the diodes across the relay contacts my circuit would die as soon as I changed direction but now it will survive for a little while and then go out randomly.
I don't have it shown but the timer is wired in a standard astable configuration with a single potentiometer to change the duty cycle.
The strange thing is that when I bench test the circuit with a smaller motor the circuit survives, so I don't know what else I can try. Every example circuit of this kind that I can find online has far less protection diodes than my design so I'm just stumped on what to try next.
Also there is a 10v zener diode connected from VCC to ground of the timer to hopefully clamp the voltage but that still didnt help.
Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Why are you apparently paralleling two sets of contacts on each relay? You could do this with a single DPDT relay instead.

Try 100uF electrolytic across (and near) the timer IC power pins and increase R1 to 1kΩ. Lower PWM frequency if necessary.

Those are just the kind of relays i had on hand, there's no specific reason behind it.

Also i do have a main supply capacitor and bypass cap at the timer, i just didnt show any of the timer connections bcause i thought it was very standard.  As for lowering the pwm, it's already pretty low at 250hz. What would raising the gate resistor value accomplish? The mosfet doesnt have any issues at all. It doesn't even get warm and when i probe the gate i dont see any ringing, just a clean 12v square wave with just a little bit of slope to the rising edge. I'll try it if you think it would help.

@DanielZ See my answer below for a more detailed explanation than is appropriate for comments.

The schematics are hard to follow. Is the connection between pins A2 and 22 of the left relay intentional or just a drawing error?

@Burglups The diodes are not too slow on turn-on. Some power is lost on turn-off due to the reverse recovery time, but no diode's forward recovery is that bad. But yes, it would be better to use fast-recovery diodes, schottky+zeners, or some other method. I've not used varistors for this before, but they would probably work too as you note.

@Burglups When a diode is called "slow", it usually refers to the diode's reverse recovery or forward recovery time, so that's what I thought you were referring to. Yes, a diode alone will take a while to turn off a relay, though ten ms seems a bit high to me.

@Burglups Personal experience. Maybe it is on the order of 10 ms, that just feels a little longer than I would have thought. I maintain that an unqualified "slow" as a descriptor for diodes would refer to the recovery time, though.

@Burglups I don't know what you mean by "set it in doubt". I don't know how this got so off-topic either, when all I'm doing is attempting to agree with you and you seem to keep attacking me for being mistaken when I said nothing more confident than "seems a bit high".

To answer your various questions, the connection from A2 and 22 of the left relay is an error. The delay that the diode introduces to the relay doesn't matter in this case because my polarity switch has a center position where both relays are off before the next relay turns on. I wasn't very selective on which diodes i used and they probably aren't the ideal diodes for this application but the circuit seems to work perfectly now that i found the problem that i pisted about below.

For anyone who sees this in the future, the actual problem was not a lack of diode protection. The problem turned out to be a small strand of wire from a pin of potentiometer was touching the housing, which zero'd out the timing capacitor and made the timer's output stay high and the mosfet to also stay on which is why the rest of the circuit still worked fine.

You need a decoupling cap from VDD to GND on the 555.
It is possible that inductive spikes from the motor are generating spikes on VCC (& VDD).

I am suggesting that you increase the gate resistor because it's possible that due to layout etc. there is significant inductance in the source circuit. The 22 ohm resistor does two things- it causes the MOSFET to switch very quickly (and we know V = L * di/dt) and it can conduct significant current back into the 7555. If enough current flows the wrong way it can cause the 7555 to latch up, causing it to conduct a large amount of Vdd current and the chip will quickly become permanently inert.
At 250Hz PWM frequency 1k ohm should be no problem for switching speed, but if you feel you need a faster drive, you can isolate the gate from the 7555 with a couple transistors as so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can use common jellybean transistors such as shown, 2N4401/2N4403, 8050/8550, C1815/A1015, BCwhatever etc.

Ok i will change the resistor and see what that does.
